# Espiral en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, matriz, elementos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este ejercicio y no logro hacerlo hasta ahora esta es la lógica que he tratado de poner, pero no sé si voy por buen camino o si por el contrario me estoy complicando más de lo que debería alguno podría darme alguna ayuda.

```
               function sumDiagonals (n) {
      // Crear una matriz de n x n [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
      const arr = Array(n).fill().map(() => Array(n).fill(0))
      // Crear una variable para almacenar la suma
      let sum = 0
      // Crear una variable para almacenar la posicion x
      let x = Math.floor(n / 2)
      // Crear una variable para almacenar la posicion y
      let y = Math.floor(n / 2)
      // Crear una variable para almacenar el numero
      let num = 1
      // Crear una variable para almacenar la direccion
      let dir = 'right'
      // Crear una variable para almacenar el numero de pasos
      let steps = 1
      // Crear una variable para almacenar el numero de pasos que se han dado
      let stepCount = 0
      // Crear una variable para almacenar el numero de veces que se ha cambiado de direccion
      let stepChange = 0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debería ir en texto y en su respectivo formato, no en imágenes...

Comment: Me sale error me dice que no puede ser únicamente código mi pregunta

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Aiden el ejercicio también debería ir como texto excepto las ilustraciones o cosas que no se puedan mostrar de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lado = 1003;
let tamaño = lado * lado + 1;
let diagIzq = 1;
let diagDer = 1;
let indice = 1;
let salto = 2;
let entradas = 0;
let primerDiag = true;

for( let i = 1; i < tamaño; i++ ) {
    if( i == indice ) {
        if( primerDiag ) {
            diagIzq += i;
            primerDiag = false;
        }
        else {
            diagDer += i;
            primerDiag = true;
        }
        indice += salto;
        entradas++;
    }
    if( entradas == 4  ) {
        entradas = 0;
        salto += 2;
    }
}
console.log( "diag sur = " + diagIzq + "  diag norte = " + diagDer );
console.log( "la suma es = " + ( diagIzq + diagDer ));
```

Hola @Aiden312, acá te dejo una posible solución.
Para entender como funciona, hay que mirar el **dibujito** del ejemplo.
Seguramente habrás observado, que en la primer rueda, el número que tienes que cargar (sin importar a cual diagonal), se distancia a dos del anterior, en la segunda rueda, a cuatro, después a seis... etc.
Lo que hace este método, es recorrer los valores de las distintas posiciones de los números, cuando el valor coincide con la variable indice, carga el valor en la diagonal correspondiente, aumenta el valor de **indice** con **salto** y agrega 1 a la cuenta de **entradas**, cuando inserta 4 valores (terminó una rueda), aumenta el valor de **salto** en 2.
PD: puedes obviar las dos diagonales y usar una sola variable para cargar el resultado final... espero haberme explicado bien y que te sea de utilidad.